# Error http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector" in laravel with angular js

Tags: angularjs, laravel, openrainbowapi

Haii friends, I need your help
I have a problem that I do not know, when I try to combine laravel and angular js, Can you guys help me.

*"Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector"*

For more details I created a file **index.php** And this is his code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sample" lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Starter - Laravel & AngularJS</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <title>Rainbow SDK for Web</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./res/appLogo.png"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,cyrillic">
       <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/angular/js/components/connection/connectionCmp.css"> -->
        <script src="{{ asset('resources/build/js/components.js') }}"></script>
       <!--  <script src="./resources/angular/js/components/connection/connectionCmp.js"></script> -->
</head>
    <body>
      <!-- Demo specific part -->

<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height" ng-controller="sampleController">   

    <div class="content">
        <div class="view page page-home" ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Angular Init Here -->

<script src="//api.openrainbow.com/sdk/web/libs/loader-sdk.min.js" data-main="./config.json"></script>

<!-- App JS Files - All Controllers -->
<script src="{{ asset('resources/angular/js/application.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('resources/angular/js/MainController.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is **application.js** file for its route

```
var sample = angular.module('sample', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

sample.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
        controller: 'sampleController',
        templateUrl: '../partials/dashboard.html'
    })


    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'resources/angular/partials/dashboard.html'
    })
});
```

And this is **MainController.js** file for its controller

```
var sample = angular.module("sample", ["sdk"]);

sample.controller("sampleController", [
    "$rootScope",
    "rainbowSDK", 
    function($rootScope, sdk) {
        "use strict";

        console.log("[DEMO] :: Rainbow IM Application");

        var onReady = function onReady() {
            console.log("[DEMO] :: Rainbow SDK is ready!");
        };

        var onLoaded = function onLoaded() {
            console.log("[DEMO] :: Rainbow SDK has been loaded!");

            sdk.initialize().then(function() {
                console.log("[DEMO] :: Rainbow SDK is initialized!");
            }).catch(function() {
                console.log("[DEMO] :: Something went wrong with the SDK...");
            });
        };

        $rootScope.$on(sdk.RAINBOW_ONREADY, onReady);

        $rootScope.$on(sdk.RAINBOW_ONLOADED, onLoaded);

        sdk.useAngularEvents(true);
        sdk.load();

        return true;
    }
]);
```

I hope my friends can help me,Thanks.

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $injector:modulerr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the dependency injection to the main module and remove it from the controller,

**application.js**

```
var sample = angular.module('sample', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate','sdk']);
```

**MainController.js**

```
var sample = angular.module("sample");
```

Comment: Sorry sajeetharan, I try but still can not